# How to dismiss the keyboard in appium using Java?

Tags: java, android, appium

This code just aims to find the textbox and send some text to it.
When it does that the keyboard appears on the android device.How to dismiss it after the sendKeys.

```
@Test
    public static void test_demo() throws Exception {
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("mytextfield"));
        element.sendKeys("test");
        //how do I dismiss keyboard which appears on my android device after sendKeys?  
    }
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten your question text.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`driver.hideKeyboard()` will only work with `AppiumDriver`. 
I am using java-client-2.2.0.jar that contains this capability.

Comment: Works in Javascript client as well.

Comment: `if(getDriver().isKeyboardShown()) {
  getDriver().hideKeyboard();
}`

Answer (score 8):

Best way is to use the back button.

```
driver.navigate().back(); // For older version of appium
```

Comment: This will work on some android api's and will fail on others.
in some android Api's it will return you back to previous activity not hiding keyboard

Comment: you can check this link for my proper answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21704358/how-to-locate-element-in-uiautomator-if-native-keyboard-come-before-your-applica/24359760#24359760

Answer (score 8):

Add these desired capabilities values if you want to disable the keyboard on your android selenium tests.

```
capabilities.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", true);
capabilities.setCapability("resetKeyboard", true);
```

Comment: Keyboard still pops up in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Please use Appium 1.0

Add libraries or add maven dependency of Appium Java client:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Create driver instance in the following way:

```
AppiumDriver driver=null;
driver= new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);
```

And use the following function to hide the keyboard:

```
driver.hideKeyboard();
```

Comment: Appium 1.1.0 throws a method not yet implemented when calling hideKeyboard()

Comment: hideKeyboard() is implemented in java-client 1.5.0

Comment: What if keyboard is not present for some reason (e.g. on emulator keyboard does not show up on send_keys). In this case you'll navigate back and the test goes wrong. You need to check somehow if the OSK is present

Answer (score 2):

I use `driver.hideKeyboard();` every time I'm using `sendKeys()` to type something. Works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static AndroidDriver driver= null;
......

driver.hideKeyboard();
```

will work perfectly based on my experience.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for those who are not using `AppiumDriver`:

```
((AppiumDriver)driver).hideKeyboard();
```

Answer (score 0):

`driver.hideKeyboard();` some times does not work.
Because while running testcase keyboard not appear fast, So testcase fail.
If I use `Thread.sleep(5000);` before `hideKeyboard` method, it's working very fine for me every time.

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.getMessage();
}
driver.hideKeyboard();
```