# Appium - Not able to access hideKeyboard() method

Tags: java, appium, appium-android

I see AndroidDriver hierarchy as below.

AndroidDriver -> AppiumDriver -> DefaultGenericMobileDriver -> MobileDriver -> HidesKeyboard

Using appium java-client 7.2.0 version.

HidesKeyboard interface has implemented hideKeyboard() method. The method is not available, when I am trying with object of AndroidDriver.

[image]

I want the below code to work. Any clues?

```
AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> androidDriver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
androidDriver.hideKeyboard();
```

As per the official documentation, hideKeyboard() method should be accessible.

http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/keys/hide-keyboard/

[image]

Comment: What of the appium version?

Comment: Using appium java-client 7.2.0 version.

Comment: This is maven project? if yes, I suspect you have selenium dependencies, try remove it. Maybe it conflict with your `java-client`, and it seems like your question too broad, please provide more information for this question.

Comment: By the way you can use `driver.navigate().back();` if you want close keyboard, when keyboard is open it will do back action and it will close the keyboard.

Comment: Per the documentation at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220067/how-to-dismiss-the-keyboard-in-appium-using-java, the said solution works for only old version of appium. Can you please let me know why the hideKeyboard() method is not accessible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide your keyBoard during the whole tests, use this:

```
caps.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", true);
caps.setCapability("resetKeyboard", true);
```

Comment: Yes, this works out if keyboard is to be hidden for the whole test. I am curious why the hideKeyboard() method is not available.